# Two equivalent definitions of the coLie sheaf for a family of elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, moduli-space

Let $f: E\rightarrow S$ be a family of elliptic curves, i.e. a proper flat morphism of schemes whose geometric fibers are genus $1$ curves, along with a section $e:S\rightarrow E$. Then there is an invertible $\mathcal O_S$-module $\omega = f_*\Omega^1_{E/S}$ on $S$, sometimes called $\mathrm{coLie}(E)$ because at $s\in S$ the fiber of $\omega^{-1}$ at $s$ is the Lie algebra of the elliptic curve $E_s$.

I've seen it claimed that $\omega\cong e^*\Omega^1_{E/S}$, though it's not clear to me why this is true, or how even to define a map $f_*\Omega^1_{E/S}\rightarrow e^*\Omega^1_{E/S}$. I'd appreciate an explanation of why this isomorphism holds (or a reference giving such an explanation). Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849517/are-pushforward-and-pullback-by-zero-section-of-diffrentials-isomorphic-in-e/3856012#3856012

Comment: Yep, it sure is. Thought I had been thorough searching, but apparently I missed this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'll mark this as a duplicate and you can provide your feedback to the answer there.